# WinRT component DLL that contains only interfaces?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, windows-runtime, windows-phone

Is it possible to write a WinRT Component DLL that only contains class interfaces? No code, just declarations of interfaces.

Comment: Perhaps this might help you?
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithnativecode/thread/cb06c393-bcf2-4302-96bb-1ca1f06709d3

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't. It talks about a different problem.

Comment: The link doesn't have anything to do with my question. I've edited the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From experimentation, there doesn't appear to be a way to create a DLL that just contains interfaces declared in .h files. I have, however, found a work-around where if the WinRT Component DLL project contains a "dummy" cpp file that simply includes the interface .h files, the DLL (and winmd file) export the interfaces properly.